# Flagging warning?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, flag-history, flag-ban

I was about to flag a question for something better suited for Server Fault. When doing so I noticed I had a warning about a declined flag which is new for me.

Is this a new change or does this mean I'm close to lose my ability to flag?

[image]

Unsure if this matters, however:

> post flags 255
>
> helpful 150
>
> declined 13

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 3 levels of flag warnings that you can get depending on how many "recent" flags you had declined.  Recent in this case means over the last 7 days.

- For cases where you flagged fewer than 10 posts, you will get a **warning** based only on the status if your previous flag *"Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post"*
- For cases where you've flagged at least 10 and you've had more than 10% declined, you will get the message: *"Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!"*
- The final scenario is when you will be blocked from flagging.  This occurs when 25% or more of your recent flags have been declined: *"Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post"*

So in your case, you are in the middle category - 10% or more of your flags have been declined in the last 7 days.  At this point you can still flag, but you are on your way to getting banned if the declines keep coming.  You should look at your flag history and see the declines and what messages the moderators have send back to you.  If you keep going and get to 25%, then you will get banned for a period of time (essentially until you have fewer than 25% of your flags in the last 7 days)

You can read all of the details in [Allow recovery from flag hellban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405)