# What kind of suspensions are there on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, review-suspension, account-suspension, banning

I could not find any information on what kind of account suspensions you can face.

What kind of suspensions are there? What is the worst suspension a user can face other than banning them indefinitely?

How does the moderator decide if a user should become banned? Does there have to be a concession between moderators for banning a user?

Comment: Well, there's one user who's banned for the next 7 years, and has been for at least 6 years already, that's pretty bad

Comment: You can't be banned indefinitely, but you can be banned for a very long definitely.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was more curious to see what kind of bans there is and how one can become banned.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Comment: Are you just talking about suspensions of the entire account, or e.g. review suspensions, etc.?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery, all of the above.

Comment: @nick 7 years? That's nothing. There is one user  "This account is temporarily suspended network-wide. The suspension period ends on Mar 18 '92 at 16:28.", ie more than 70 years. On his chat profile, the ban is for 273 years (3 centuries).

Comment: @DavidPostill that assumes '92 is 2092.  It could b 2292 and be of similar duration as chat

Comment: @DavidPostill I did think there was a longer one, but couldn't remember who/find them

Answer (score 16):

There are 5 main types of bans/suspensions and only one of them is of indefinite length.  Some are manual and some are automatic.

[**Review Suspension (formerly known as Review Ban)**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275736/review-bans-should-escalate-beyond-30-days/287296#287296) - this is either manual by a moderator or automatic when you fail enough audits. This type of suspension prevents you from participating in the review queues, but your other interactions with the site are unaffected.

The duration of the suspension given by moderator can be set manually and they have their own criteria for how long to set a suspension.  But the automatic suspension always scales based on your last review suspension length and time since your suspension ended (less than 30 days, double your last suspension length; more than 30 days, the length is half).

[**Flag Ban**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394500/flagging-warning/394502#394502) - a completely automatic process that limits your ability to flag posts if you had enough declined in the previous 7 days.

[**Suggested Edit Ban**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing) - another automatic ban that prevents you from suggesting edits to posts.  This is based on the number of rejected edits and accepted edits over the [previous 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337).  There's also [rate limiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits/281202#281202) that will essentially impose a very short duration "ban" to prevent someone from spamming too many suggested edits.

Moderators can also [levy a manual ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits/252991#252991) to block a specific user from suggesting edits. These are rare, since moderators can levy other suspensions.

[**Post Ban**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) - another wholly automatic ban that prevents you from posting new questions or answers (there are separate question bans and answer bans).  This is based on a secret algorithm that measures how well-received your past posts have been.  This is the only indefinite ban that exists on the site (although you are usually given another attempt to ask every 6 months to see if your asking/answering skills have improved).

[**Account Suspension**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) - the last type of ban is 100% manual and reserved for only serious infractions of the rules.  These are always accompanied by a message from the moderators (both to your notifications inbox as well as your email). Basically, your ability to interact with the site is removed and your reputation is temporarily set to 1.

The length of the suspension is issued in days and can last for up to 1 year.

A more serious version of the account suspension exists that will suspend you from the entire Stack Exchange network and/or for periods of longer than 1 year, but that can only be levied by a Stack Exchange Community Manager (i.e., the [Community Management Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-is-on-the-community-management-team-and-what-do-they-do), which are made up of employees of Stack Overflow).

---

There are also IP-level bans throughout the site, and [other rate limiting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) to slow users down.

Comment: There's chat suspension as well, that only affects chat :)

Comment: @Scratte Those are manual, by a mod.

Comment: Chat suspensions are also automatic if someone's suspended on the main site, usually. @10Rep They're also dished out automatically for 30 minutes IIRC for a valid flag against a user's message (verified by 10k users or mods - the system hands out an automatic suspension).

Comment: @Zoe Oh, I didn't know that. I got suspended from chat for 3 seconds once with three other users, though.

Comment: I would think that CMs have the ability to apply/remove any of the bans/suspensions/rate limitations, automatic or otherwise. Might be nice to know to whom one can appeal if one is banned. Worse comes to worst, it's just a value in a database somewhere, and someone somewhere has access to production :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm pretty sure mods, not even CMs have that power.

Comment: @10Rep Chat suspensions can be automated as well. Some bans can be removed by moderators and/or CMs, but some can't. Not even CMs can remove post bans, for example.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the other bans, there is a chat ban. Chat bans are issued in minutes, not days. You can be banned from chat by

- Sustained spam/rude flags (10k privilege to review). You get a 30 minute chat ban for **each message** that gets a sustained flag.
- Moderators can ban you for [as long as they want](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372796) (~416 days)
- If your main account is suspended, your chat account will be suspended for the same length of time.

Comment: Pst.. you forgot the auto-suspension by kick :)